# Triangle View that clips to bounds in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to put two triangle views on my view controller.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    context.closePath()

    context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.60)
    context.fillPath()
}
```

I set the background color of the view to white but it fills the whole screen because I made the width and height the size of the screen.

When I add an image view to the triangle view it fills the whole screen when I just want it to fill the triangle so then I can place another triangle beside it that is turned upside down.

[image]

Comment: "I just want it to fill the triangle" Then you're about this wrong. Draw the triangle as a _mask_.